# Git: pathspec 'path' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, wildcard, git-checkout

I want to discard my local changes for a lot of files, which names corresponds some of wildcard pattern (for example `prefix*`)

I tried do it with command:

```
git checkout prefix*
```

But got errors because of existance a local untracked files suitable for wildcards. Files are untracked because they are mentioned in `.gitignore` (e.g. *.log):

```
pathspec 'prefix.log' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How to revert a lot of files (using wildcards) if i have local untracked files with corresponding names?

Comment: Simple solution would be for a moment, comment that rule in `.gitignore` file and do the changes and revert back the file.

Comment: Don't let your shell glob the pattern.

Comment: @rajuGT Did you mean: comment, then `git add`, then `git checkout prefix*`, then 'git reset', then uncomment? It's too long.

Comment: I get this error despite the fact that the relevant files are not in `.gitignore`. It seems that Git has some trouble with wildcards in checkout statements. Git understands the exact same pathspec when passed to "git diff" but not "git checkout".

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner solution:

```
git ls-files -z 'prefix*' | xargs -0 -L1 -I '$' git checkout -- '$'
```

---

The part that is effective is to quote the pathspec so that the shell does not do the wildcard expansion.

Should also work already for

```
git checkout 'prefix*'
```